# Lua - Reflection - function parameters and docstrings?

Tags: reflection, lua

I'm coming to Lua from Python.  I am using the Lua C API.  I wonder if there is a standard method to bundle some parameter and usage information with the methods and tie it to a standard `help()` or `<method>.__doc__()`-like method.

Some ideas I had:

1) somehow put the docs in library metatable and let the users use `pairs()`:

```
static const luaL_Reg lua_mylib_funcs[] = {
    ...
    {NULL, NULL}};
```

2) print some usage info when the methods are called with no parameters.

3) create a `.help()` or a `.docs()` method for the library.

Can someone point in a "Lua-ish" direction?

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if there is **a standard method** to bundle some parameter and usage information with the methods

Nope.

> somehow put the docs in library metatable and let the users use pairs():

You could just establish a convention where if the method name is `foo` you store the docs in `foo_docs` or something like that.

```
x.foo_docs = "returns the sum of three numbers"
function x:foo(a,b,c)
   return a + b + c
end
```

> print some usage info when the methods are called with no parameters.

That would prevent you from creating methods with no parameters.

> Can someone point in a "Lua-ish" direction?

Kinda hard to say without really know why you need it and how you'd *prefer* it to work. To get something like `<method>.__doc__` you could convert a method (i.e. function) into a callable table, which would let you index it and store any metadata you want, but it would be ugly and require creating a new table per method. For instance, this would let you convert a method into a callable table:

```
local documentMethodMetatable = {}
function documentMethodMetatable.__call(t,...)
  return t.method(...)
end
function documentMethod(method, doc)
  return setmetatable({ method=method, doc=doc}, documentMethodMetatable)
end
```

Then you could write stuff like:

```
local foo = {name="Donut"}
function foo:sum(a,b,c)
  print(self.name .. " says the sum is " .. (a + b + c))
end

foo.sum = documentMethod(foo.sum, "Receives three arguments and prints their sum.")

foo:sum(2,2,3)     --> call sum
print(foo.sum.doc) --> index sum to get docs
```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen [this solution at lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/DecoratorsAndDocstrings), if that's what you're looking for?